# What is thread wrapper class in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to java. My question is what is thread wrapper class for a class. For example I have written an class 'someClass'. Now if I need to break my program in multiple threads, then how to write thread wrapper class for this class. (I know what threads are and how to break a program in multiple threads and run, but I am not understanding meaning of thread wrapper class.)
thankx

Comment: As @01es has mentioned, read Java Concurrency in Practice. These days directly working with Thread is less safe than working with ExecutorService, AtomicXYZ and the rest of the utilities in java.util.concurrent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class needs to extend the Runnable interface.  Then you'd start it like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(yourClassInstanceHere);
t.start();
```

Comment: So when I declare my class as class-name implements Runnable then it got wrapped??

Comment: No.  Thread's constructor takes a Runnable argument.  It's wrapped when you give your instance to the Thread constructor.

Answer (score 6):

There is class [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), which represents a single thread. There an interface [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), which can be accepted by a Thread instance for executions.

IMO a good advice is to consult [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) book -- the definitive guide to Java concurrency. Really helpful.